# TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object appears only when I run the same script in a parameterized function

Tags: python

I am trying to plot the progress of COVID-19 vaccinations over time in different countries. The script was working fine as long as it is reading and preprocessing the data separately for each country. I get the error when I try to run the same script on a list of country names using a function.
Checking Stackflow I see the solutions proposed to this type of error has been case specific and I can't draw a general conclusion to apply it to my case.
Does anyone have any idea how I can  fix the issue?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

mpl.style.use(['ggplot'])
parameter = 'total_vaccinations'

def covid_vaccines(countries):
    covid_vaccinations = []
    for con in countries:       
        url = "https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/vaccinations/country_data/" + con + ".csv?raw=true"
        df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col = 0)
        #print(df.head, type(df))
        country = df.loc[con,['date', parameter]]
        #print(country.head, type(country))
        #converting the dataframe to series with 'date' as index
        country = country.set_index('date').squeeze()
        country.name = con
        print(country.head, type(country))
        covid_vaccinations = pd.concat([covid_vaccinations, country], axis = 1)
    return covid_vaccinations

countries = ['Sweden']
vaccinations = covid_vaccines(countries)
vaccinations.plot()
```